# API calls in Unity works in debug mode But in Build it says Cannot resolve destination host

Tags: rest, unity-game-engine, networking, build

I am facing this issue in Unity version 2022.3.10.f1. Its a unity XR project for VR devlopment. All are working but only thing I am stuck at REST API calls are working fine in unity debug window but its not working as expected inside VR built. ONLY error I see is:

> **"Cannot resolve destination host"**.

Please Help me with this.

Updated the AndroidManifest.xml as below

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <application>
        <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:theme="@StyLe/UnityThemeSelector">
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

3.) code REST API call

```cshrap
public static IEnumerator GetRequest(string uri)
{
    using (UnityWebRequest webRequest = new UnityWebRequest(uri, "GET"))
    {
        webRequest.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
        
        // Send the request and wait for a response
        yield return webRequest.SendWebRequest();
        
        if (webRequest.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)
        {
            // Log any errors
            Debug.Log(": Error: " + webRequest.error);
        }
        else
        {
            // Log the response
            Debug.Log(": Received: " + webRequest.downloadHandler.text);
        }
    }
}
```

called for example as

```
GetRequest("https://www.google.com/")
```

I am facing this issue in Unity version 2022.3.10.f1. Based on few answers and documentation I followed few ways fix it (mentioned below).

1. enabled internet to required in project setting > Player > publishing settings.
2. Used Custom manifest file where I mentioned Internet and local Access requested.

Tried different ways but not luck. Please help me in this issue.

Comment: what is the host you are trying to reach? and by "in a build" you also mean it is running on a different device right?

Comment: I just want to call google.com for testing. Added the code the above Question

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in Unity when using OpenXR plugin 1.8 it seems. I have it as well, and even with a custom manifest I cannot get UnityWebRequests to work, or any HTTP calls from the Unity app on my Quest. Apparantly an update added some strange "force disable Internet" option in the OpenXR plugin that cannot be disabled, but it has been reported as a bug to Unity:
https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-removes-android-permission-internet-in-the-build-apk-after-build-is-completed.1466654/

Seems you either have to find a way to downgrade OpenXR to 1.7 or wait for Unity to fix it.